# Position not getting updated in events c++

Tags: c++

I want the variable curr_pos_x and curr_pos_y to hold the updated values of the player but whenever i press any up/down/left/down key the second time the position is set to reset and then updated according to the button clicked.

```
while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
            
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        {
            window.close();
        }


        if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
        {
            float curr_pos_x;
            float curr_pos_y;
            
            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
            {
                // move right...
                curr_pos_x = PLAYER_START_X + PLAYER_WIDTH;
                curr_pos_y = PLAYER_START_Y;
                player.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(curr_pos_x, curr_pos_y));
            }
            else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)){
                curr_pos_x = PLAYER_START_X - PLAYER_WIDTH;
                curr_pos_y = PLAYER_START_Y;
                player.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(curr_pos_x, curr_pos_y));
            }
            else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up)){
                curr_pos_x = PLAYER_START_X;
                curr_pos_y = PLAYER_START_Y - PLAYER_HEIGHT;
                player.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(curr_pos_x, curr_pos_y));
            }
            else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down)){
                curr_pos_x = PLAYER_START_X;
                curr_pos_y = PLAYER_START_Y + PLAYER_HEIGHT;
                player.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(curr_pos_x, curr_pos_y));
            }
        }
    }
    window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
    window.draw(player);
    window.display();
}
```

Comment: What operating system/framework is involved here?

Comment: Before handing Key pressed event you need to assign player's current position to `curr_pos_x` and `curr_pos_y`. and then handle the key press events. Currently you are always assigning this to `PLAYER_START_X` or `PLAYER_START_Y`

Comment: Well, you always set the variables to the same values, so... I would recommend that you add a "move" function to the player, which can take a relative displacement.